# In lucene 4, IndexReader.getTermVector(docID, fieldName) returns null for every doc

Tags: lucene

I'm using the newly released Lucene 4, and I understand that the API related to document term vectors has changed considerably. I've read through the migration doc and related various and sundry blog mailing list posts, and I believe I'm using the API correctly. However, I always get a null Terms reference back from IndexReader.getTermVector(). Here's what I'm doing:

```
// Indexing, given "bodyString" as a String containing document text
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("body", bodyString, Field.Store.YES));
MyIndexWriter.addDocument(doc);


// much later, enumerating document term vectors for "body" field for every doc
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.maxDoc(); ++i) {
  final Terms terms = Reader.getTermVector(i, "body");
  if (terms != null) {
    int numTerms = 0;
    // record term occurrences for corpus terms above threshold
    term = terms.iterator(term);
    while (term.next() != null) {
      ++numTerms;
    }
    System.out.println("Document " + i + " had " + numTerms + " terms");
  }
  else {
    System.err.println("Document " + i + " had a null terms vector for body");
  }
}
```

Of course, it prints out that I have null term vectors for every doc, i.e., Reader.getTermVector(i, "body") always returns null.

When I look at the index in Luke, I have documents which have stored body fields. However, when I click on "TV" button (in the Documents tab) whilst having the body field highlighted, Luke tells me "Term Vector not available." Do I need to add some other kind of option to record this information when indexing?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Jon

*Update*
I should note that the `IndexReader` in question is an instance of `SlowCompositeReaderWrapper`, which is wrapping a `DirectoryReader`. I am using a `SlowCompositeReaderWrapper` because I want the corpus term frequencies as well, and it's not precisely clear how to iterate all docs over all `IndexReader` leaves (do doc IDs get reused across them?, etc.).

Is SlowCompositeReaderWrapper the culprit?

Answer (score 12):

According to the [TextField API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) it is "A field that is indexed and tokenized, without term vectors."  If you wish to store TermVectors, you should just use a [Field](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html), and set it to store TermVectors in the [FieldType](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html).

Something like:

```
Document doc = new Document();
FieldType type = new FieldType();
type.setIndexed(true);
type.setStored(true);
type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
Field field = new Field("body", bodyString, type);
doc.add(field);
MyIndexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that after posting.Luke now reports the term vectors, but IndexReader.getTermVector() as used above is still returning null. I am going to try to retrieve the Document, then get the body Field, then iterate the Terms and see whether that works.

Comment: `getTermVector()` returns null for every document (that is, not getting caught on documents left over from previous tests, or deleted documents)?

Comment: Yeah. I deleted the index folder entirely and re-indexed. Still nulls. I'm now using this for FieldType options:

`FieldType BodyOptions = new FieldType();
BodyOptions.setIndexed(true);
BodyOptions.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
BodyOptions.setStored(true);
BodyOptions.setStoreTermVectors(true);
BodyOptions.setTokenized(true);
// ...
doc.add(new Field("body", bodyString, BodyOptions);
`

Answer (score 2):

You are using TextField, [a field that is indexed and tokenized, **without term vectors**](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html). That's why you will get null on getTermVector().
Instead of using TextField, construct Field with your customized FieldType which setStoreTermVectors to true.