# What is docID in IndexReader.getTermVector(int docID ,String field) in Lucene 8.5.1 and how does it work?

Tags: java, lucene, posting

I am trying to get all of terms and related postings which called `Terms` from a Lucene`s document field(i.e. How to calculate term frequeny in Lucene?). According to [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector(int,java.lang.String)) there is a method to do that:

`public final Terms getTermVector​(int docID, String field) throws IOException`

> Retrieve term vector for this document and field, or null if term vectors were not indexed. The returned Fields instance acts like a single-document inverted index (the docID will be 0).

There is a field called `int docID`. What is this?? for a given document what is the id field of that and how does Lucene recognize that?
According to Lucene's documentation i have used `StringField` as id and it is not a `int`.

```
import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
Document doc = new Document();
Field idField = new StringField("id",post.Id,Field.Store.YES);
Field bodyField = new TextField("body", post.Body, Field.Store.YES);
doc.add(idField);
doc.add(bodyField);
```

I have five question accordingly:

1. How does Lucene recognize the `id` field is used as `docId` for this document? or even Lucene does it or not ??
2. I used `String` for id but this method give a `int`. Does it cause a problem?
3. Is there any appropriate method to get postings?
4. I have used `TextField` . Is there any way to retrieve term vector(`Terms`) of that field? I don't want to re-index my doc as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363377/in-lucene-4-indexreader-gettermvectordocid-fieldname-returns-null-for-every), because it is too large (35-GB).
5. Is there any way to get terms count and get each term frequency from `TextField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate term frequency we can use `IndexReader.getTermVector(int docID ,String field)`. `int docID` is a field which refers to document id created by Lucene. You can retrieve `docID` by the code follow:

```
String index = "index/AIndex/";
String query = "the query text"

IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("docField", analyzer);
Query lQuery = parser.parse(query);

]TopDocs results = searcher.search(lQuery ,  requiredHits);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int numTotalHits = (int) results.totalHits.value;

for (int i = start; i < numTotalHits; i++)
 {
   int docID = hits[i].doc;
   Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docID, "docField");
 }
```

Each `termVector` object have term and frequency related to a document field and you can retrieve that by the following code:

```
private HashMap<String,Long> termsFrequency = new HashMap<>();
TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
int allTermFrequency=0;
BytesRef term;

while ((term = itr.next()) != null){
  String termText = term.utf8ToString();
  long tf = itr.totalTermFreq();
  termsFrequency.put(termText, tf);
  allTermFrequency += itr.totalTermFreq();
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget to set  store term vector as i explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321816/term-document-matrix-in-lucene/62439994#62439994) (Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363377/in-lucene-4-indexreader-gettermvectordocid-fieldname-returns-null-for-every)) when you are indexing documents. If you index your document without setting to store term vector, the method `getTermVector` will return `null`. All kind of predefind Lucene Field deactivated this option by default. So you need to set it.